# How Can I register a type library just for the current user?

Tags: .net, deployment, com, registration, typelib

I have a type library called `MyCOMAddin.tlb`, that I have extracted using `tlbexp.exe` from a `MyCOMAdd.dll`. This is a .NET COM exposed class written in C#. This dll is register at per user level.

The question is

- Is there any way I can also register `MyCOMAddin.tlb` just the current user?

I tried `regtlibv12.exe`, but it registers for all-users.
This in inconvenient, because if any user un-install the Add-in on the machine, the other users, which will still have access to the dll in late binding, will not have access anymore to the typelibrary.

I am using Inno setup to deploy the add-in, so I could write the keys directly in the registry. But I don't have any idea of which keys and where to write them.

I wish `regtlibv12.exe` had a `/peruser` option.

Comment: I don't think so.  The Program Files and Windows are shared.   Users have individual data.

Comment: MyCOMAddin.dll is registered at user level. Why its type library couldn't be registered just for the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't impossible, but of course you'll be heading for some complications.  First off, it isn't sufficient to just register the type library locally, you also need to register the CLSIDs locally or it still won't work correctly.  The job done by Regasm.exe.  Do favor its /tlb command line option (without a file) over running regtlib.  And beware that whatever programming tool uses the type library may need some extra registry keys to recognize the library as a component, the "Control" key is common for example.

Professional installers do not rely on tools like Regasm or Regtlib to write the keys at install time, they write the keys themselves.  Which of course requires knowing what those keys are.  One way is to observe the install tool writing the keys with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  Albeit that it tends to generate a lot of info.  You'll find a dedicated tool in the [WiX project](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/60102), Heat.exe is the "harvesting" tool.  Modify everything you found that way from using HKCR or HKLM to using HKCU instead.  HKCR maps to HKCU\Software\Classes.  Possibly with Wow6432Node added for 64-bit operating systems.

And be sure you actually *need* the type library registered.  It is only necessary if you are using the component in another programming environment.  And the corner case of using the object created on an STA thread and calling it from another thread, the type library is used by the standard marshaller to marshal the call across apartments.  And don't forget about reg-free COM with a manifest so no registry modifications are required at all.  It isn't clear whether that would apply here.

Comment: Hi, I would like the typelibrary registered, bacause this COMAddin is going to be called from VBA. Do you know of any utility that produce form me a .reg file with all the entries I need to make to the registry to register the type library? The kind of result I get if I use RegAsm.exe "MyCOMAddIn.ddl" /regfile. RegAsm does not tell me the entries for the type lib, it just list the entries to register for COM for the dll.

Comment: RegAsm.exe "MyComAddIn.dll" /tlb /regfile does not work, as you point out. So I don't know as the moment of any way to get a .reg file with the entries just for the tlb file.

Comment: Never tried it myself, the burden of knowing what keys matter.  Readily apply the other ways I documented to get the registry keys.  It would be useful if you actually try them instead of complaining about it.  You are trying to do something against the grain so you're a bit on your own finding ways to make it work if you don't also know what keys matter.  Pretty doggone sure that ProcMon and Heat will work.

Comment: Hi, I managed to find the keys using winmerge. I need now to find a way to write them to the registry during installation

Comment: For future readers: ProcMon works nicely, the relevant include filters are `Process Name contains regasm.exe`, `Operation is RegCreateKey` and `Operation is RegSetValue`. This reduces the "lot of info" mentioned by Hans to the relevant subset.